# How to take an array of JSON data while omitting certain data?

Tags: python, json

I have a json data containing an array of SAT scores and their corresponding schools.

Input: `[{"num_of_sat_test_takers":"s","sat_critical_reading_avg_score":"s","sat_math_avg_score":"s","sat_writing_avg_score":"s","school_name":"HUDSON HIGH SCHOOL OF LEARNING TECHNOLOGIES"}, {"num_of_sat_test_takers":"91","sat_critical_reading_avg_score":"383","sat_math_avg_score":"423","sat_writing_avg_score":"366","school_name":"UNIVERSITY NEIGHBORHOOD HIGH SCHOOL"}, {num_of_sat_test_takers":"70","sat_critical_reading_avg_score":"377","sat_math_avg_score":"402","sat_writing_avg_score":"370","school_name":"EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL"}]`

Expected Output: `"[[383, 423, 366, "UNIVERSITY NEIGHBORHOOD HIGH SCHOOL"], [377, 402, 370, "EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL"]]"`

I only want to take an array consisting of the SAT reading score,SAT math score, SAT writing score, and the corresponding school name while omitting out schools that doesn't contain any valid SAT scores such as "HUDSON HIGH SCHOOL OF LEARNING TECHNOLOGIES". Here is my attempt at it. Now how do I omit out the schools that doesn't contain any valid SAT scores?

```
def keyData(data):
    json_str = [[float(e["sat_critical_reading_avg_score"]), 
    float(e["sat_math_avg_score"]), float(e["sat_writing_avg_score"]), 
    e["school_name"]] for e in data]
    return json.dumps(json_str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
def keyData(data):
  result = []
  for ele in data:
    try:
      result.append([
        int(ele['sat_critical_reading_avg_score']),
        int(ele['sat_math_avg_score']),
        int(ele['sat_writing_avg_score']),
        ele['school_name']
      ])
    except:
      pass
  return result
```

If the `element` doesn't have defined any of the propieties or the value isn't an integer an error will be thrown, tha append won't happen and the execution will jump to the `except` block, where nothing will happend and we repeat this for all the elements in the data.